# Removing multiple words from NSString using componentsSeparatedByString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, string-formatting

I wonder is there a good way of removing multiple words/tags using the `componentsSeperatedByString` in `NSString`? The only idea that struck me was to call this method 3 times to remove all of my defined tags to be removed. But that doesn´t seem to be such good style. So is there a better way of doing this?

```
#define REMOVE_TAG_1 @"cs193pspot"
#define REMOVE_TAG_2 @"portrait"
#define REMOVE_TAG_3 @"landscape"

// Formats the subtitle by removing the defined tags
- (NSString *)formatSubtitle:(NSString *)subtitle
{
    NSArray *tagsToKeep = [subtitle componentsSeparatedByString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",REMOVE_TAG_1]];

    NSLog(@"%@",[tagsToKeep description]);
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: For removal you'll want.. stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: withString:

Comment: This isn't nice either: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",REMOVE_TAG_1]` as it's equivalent to `REMOVE_TAG_1`...

Comment: in continuation to trojanfoe which is again equivalnt to cs193pspot

Comment: well... these comments are... unusual

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the tags are separated by spaces, I'd first split the string into an array of words:

```
NSArray *arrayOfTagsToFilter = @[ REMOVE_TAG_1, REMOVE_TAG_2, REMOVE_TAG_3 ];
NSArray *allTags = [subtitle componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

And then filter the array using `NSPredicate` to get the tags in the array that should be removed:

```
NSArray *tagsToRemove = [allTags filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@", arrayOfTagsToFilter]];

NSMutableArray *tagsToKeep = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:allTags];

[tagsToKeep removeObjectsInArray:tagsToRemove];
```

Comment: I took your idea and modified it a bit to my liking